# single element array problem with axis2 and json

Tags: java, ios, json, apache-axis

we have iphone application which communicate with back end data servers by axis2 webservice. Typically this means a RESTful API with JSON.
There’s one issue we’ve come across, where we’re dealing with an existing Web API which is presenting in JSON.The problem is where arrays are incorrectly serialized in certain cases. Specifically we’ve seen:

```
When an array has more than 1 entry, it is serialized correctly
When the array has only 1 entry, it is serialized not as an array, but as a single dictionary.
```

so how to control this from server side (java)?